# Writing to lists in nested for-loop R

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm attempting to write an R script that scrapes data from tables across several pages on a site. To accomplish this, I want to first create a list of the specific pages to be scraped. The addresses for the pages to be scraped follow format "www.urlpart1/[year]/urlpart2/[page]", where [year] is the range 2003 through 2015 (13 elements) and [page] has values 1 through 281 in increments of 40 (8 elements); ultimately, the final list I want will have 104 elements. Here's my code:

```
#specify components of URLs
url1 <- "www.urlpart1/"
url2 <- "/urlpart2/"

#specify range of years to scrape
years <- as.list(seq(from = 2003, to = 2015, by = 1)) #13 elements

#specify specific pages within each year to scrape
pages <- as.list(seq(from = 1, to = 281, by = 40)) #8 elements

#specify length of final list of URLs for scraping
loops <- as.list(seq(from = 1, to = (length(years)*length(pages)), by = 1)) #104 elements

#create empty list for storing output of for-loop
list1 <- list()

#initialize loop
for (i in loops){
  for (j in years){
    for (k in pages){
      list1[[i]] <- paste0(url1,j,url2,k)
    }
  }
}

list1 #outputs 104 elements of last iteration of loop
```

Ultimately the list would have 104 elements that look like this:

```
"www.urlpart1/2003/urlpart2/1",
"www.urlpart1/2003/urlpart2/41",
"www.urlpart1/2003/urlpart2/81",
"www.urlpart1/2003/urlpart2/121",
"www.urlpart1/2003/urlpart2/161",
"www.urlpart1/2003/urlpart2/201",
"www.urlpart1/2003/urlpart2/241",
"www.urlpart1/2003/urlpart2/281",
"www.urlpart1/2004/urlpart2/1",
"www.urlpart1/2004/urlpart2/41",
"www.urlpart1/2004/urlpart2/81",
"www.urlpart1/2004/urlpart2/121",
"www.urlpart1/2004/urlpart2/161",
"www.urlpart1/2004/urlpart2/201",
"www.urlpart1/2004/urlpart2/241",
"www.urlpart1/2004/urlpart2/281",
...
"www.urlpart1/2015/urlpart2/1",
"www.urlpart1/2015/urlpart2/41",
"www.urlpart1/2015/urlpart2/81",
"www.urlpart1/2015/urlpart2/121",
"www.urlpart1/2015/urlpart2/161",
"www.urlpart1/2015/urlpart2/201",
"www.urlpart1/2015/urlpart2/241",
"www.urlpart1/2015/urlpart2/281"
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting a list of the correct length, but all values are the last iteration of the loop. The previous threads addressing similar problems didn't appear to address writing to lists within nested loops. I'm completely open to solutions that don't rely on for-loops. I can easily do this using Excel's GUI, but I need to improve my coding skills to make this more easily reproducible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `expand.grid` to create the combination of all the variables to have a `data.frame` output and then `paste` each row of the data.frame (`do.call(paste0,`) and convert it to a `vector`.

```
res <- do.call(paste0,expand.grid(url1, years, url2, pages))
length(res)
#[1] 104
```

If we need a `for` loop, may be this helps

```
v1 <- c()
for(i in seq_along(url1)){
  for(j in seq_along(years)){
    for(k in seq_along(url2)){
      for(m in seq_along(pages)){
        v1 <- c(v1, paste0(url1[i], years[[j]], url2[k], pages[[m]]))
                         }
                       }
                     }
             }
identical(sort(res), sort(v1))
#[1] TRUE
```